# what does 0.1% FS +/- 0.02 mean?

Tags: measurements

Let's assume a DMM is specified to have accuracy "0.1% FS +/-0.02" when used on the 50 V range.

I get that 0.1% FS means the true value will lie somewhere between measured value - 0.05 and measured value + 0.05. But what does +/- 0.02 mean here?

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/123796/152903

Comment: This gives the device accuracy due to uncertainty of values for the components in the measuring chain (resistors and capacitors and such). The measurement precision must be included in the final value of uncertainty.

Answer (score 2):

The ±0.02 is an additional uncertainty voltage that needs to be added, regardless of the full scale value.

So you would end up with **"measured value" ± 0.07 V** on the 50 V range.